# Prolog and facts database

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

Im learning Prolog and I have some questions for you. I want to learn how to do these problems not the final solution.

As a newbie I have so little knowledge about this language but I dont want to be a cheater :(

OK so my question is...

I have define a binary tree like this:

```
tree(ID_of_tree,root,ID_left_tree,ID_right_tree)
```

For example, this tree

[image]

Is defined like this

```
tree(a4,6,b3,b4).
tree(b3,7,c1,c2).
tree(c1,5,d1,nil).
tree(d1,1,nil,nil).
tree(c2,3,nil,d2).
tree(d2,4,nil,nil).
tree(b4,8,c3,c4).
tree(c3,10,nil,nil).
tree(c4,11,d3,d4).
tree(d3,9,nil,nil).
tree(d4,2,nil,nil).
```

They are facts in my facts database. So my first question is, how to identify the father of a node N in this database. For example:

```
?-father(3,a4,P).
P=7
?-father(6,a4,P).
false
```

Defining predicate father/3.

```
father(N,Abn,P).

N= Node that I want to get its father
Abn = Tree where Im looking for. If a4, this means that is the all tree in this case.
P = Father of N.
```

I was thinking to use `findall/3` but with this I have 2 problems. One this returns a list and I want to get a single number or false. And two, I dont know how to get to the base case if this must be done with recursion.

I think that I need to use some predicates like retract or asserta for example but Im not sure about this.

This is my first attempt but the output using `father(3,a4,P).` is false

```
father2(N,Abn,PA,PA):- =(N, PA).
father(N,Abn,P) :- tree(Abn,N,A1,_), tree(A1,PA,_,_), father2(N,A1,PA,P).
father(N,Abn,P) :- tree(Abn,N,_,A2), tree(A2,PA,_,_), father2(N,A2,PA,P).
```

My second attempt is this and it returns a good solution

```
father(N,Abn,P):- tree(FT,N,_,_), tree(_,P,FT,_).
father(N,Abn,P):- tree(FT,N,_,_), tree(_,P,_,FT).
```

This could be good but I have a problem with this predicate for example

```
father(3,d3,P).
P = 7
```

I should limit the search tree if Im looking in a subtree

**Ok, finally I got it. This is my finally attempt and working like charm.**

First of all I created a predicate named `check_tree/2` . This predicate check if a tree is a subtree of other tree. For example:

```
?- check_tree(c4,c2).
false

?-check_tree(d1,b3).
true
```

This is the code for the check:

```
check_tree(Abn1,Abn1).
check_tree(Ab1,Ab2):- tree(Ft,_,Ab1,_), check_tree(Ft,Ab2).
check_tree(Ab1,Ab2):- tree(Ft,_,_,Ab1), check_tree(Ft,Ab2).
```

And next I define the predicate father/3 like this:

```
father(N,Abn,P):- tree(FT,N,_,_), tree(_,P,FT,_), check_tree(FT,Abn).
father(N,Abn,P):- tree(FT,N,_,_), tree(_,P,_,FT), check_tree(FT,Abn).
```

Now I only calculate the father if the node is inside of the search subtree.

```
?- father(3,b3,P).
P=7

?- father(3,c4,P).
false
```

Special thanks to luker and Will ness for the hints and their patience.

Thanks anyway for read this question.

Comment: A node has only one "father" (unless you want the entire chain to the root node), so `findall/3` doesn't sound appropriate here. What do the arguments to your `father/3` predicate mean? I understand `a4` to be a node name, and `3` to be a node value, but why both in this query? Why not just the node name? How did you get `P=7` from `father(3, a4, P)`? `tree(b3, 7, c1, c2)` isn't the father of `a4`, but it is the father of `c2` which has the value 3. It's a little confusing...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The arguments for father/3 are:  father(node than I want to know its parent, subtree or tree inside Im gonna looking for, father of the node). The goal of this is search in a4 which is a tree maked with subtrees like b3,b4..etc. Anyways Im gonna edit this in my question for make it more clear.

Comment: In Prolog, you would normally use recursion. Since you don't show any attempts at solving this, I'm not going to write the code for you but I can give you some hints. A simple approach would be to use an auxiliary predicate: `father(Node, Tree, FatherNode, Father)` (`FatherNode` being the current candidate father node). Initially, `FatherNode` has the value of the node given by the initial `father/3` call. Do not use `retract` or `asserta`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! This is my first attempt using recursion but give me false. I edited my question with this attempt: father2(N,Abn,PA,PA):- =(N, PA).
father(N,Abn,P) :- tree(Abn,N,A1,_), tree(A1,PA,_,_), father2(N,A1,PA,P).
father(N,Abn,P) :- tree(Abn,N,_,A2), tree(A2,PA,_,_), father2(N,A2,PA,P).

Comment: you wanted a hint, a help in learning *how to code this yourself*. Now you want help with a specific code? these are two different questions. I answered your original one.

Comment: Hi @WillNess I dont want an specific code, Im only showing my attempt. Anyways, thanks all of you for your hints! I edited my question with a new attempt ! :)

Comment: If the node value uniquely identifies the node, why do you need the "tree id"?

Comment: Why `=(N, PA)`? Why not just `N = PA`?

Comment: @lurker I need the tree id cause with these I know which tree belongs to other. For example: tree(a4,6,b3,b4).  means that the trees with id b3 and b4 are a subtree of a4. This maybe is usefull for check the descent of a tree in the search.

Comment: Or... `tree(6, 7, 8)` could mean that tree nodes 7 and 8 are directly below tree node 6. Again, if the node values are unique. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to search in a tree yourself - you already have it taken down to pieces (nodes) in your database. Prolog will search it for you.

You already have

```erlang
father1(3, a4, P):-             % first approximation
    P = 7.
```

This is the first approximation to your predicate. Try it:

> ?- father1(3,a4,7). 
>   **true.** 
>   ?- father(6,a4,P). 
>   **false.**

Correct! But it is also the case that

```erlang
father2(3, a4, P):-              % second approximation
    tree(c2,3,nil,d2), 
    ( tree(b3,7,c1,c2) ; tree(b3,7,c2,c1) ), 
    P = 7.
```

and so, also

```erlang
father3(3, a4, P):-               % third approximation
    tree(C2, 3, Nil, D2), 
    ( tree(B3, P, C1, C2) ; tree(B3, P, C2, C1) ).
```

Do you see where I'm going with this?

Two remarks. First, why this representation, and not just as a term? Will your trees have shared branches in them? Cycles?

Second,  `a4` isn't used here. Why should you need it at all? Do you envisage duplicates in your tree and want to restrain your search to a sub-tree?

But if this isn't an oversight on your part, and you really do want to constrain your search, you can augment the above `father/3` predicate to be used as a building block for this: continue searching for a father until you hit the one you're searching for (i.e. `a4` in this case) -- or not (i.e. did not encounter it on your way up, meaning you're in the wrong part of the tree). You'll need to tweak it to find not only the value, but also the ID of the father (add a fourth argument to it).

---

*edit:* Here's how you could go about it:

```erlang
father4(Three, A4, P, B3):-               % fourth approximation
    tree(C2, Three, Nil, D2), 
    ( tree(B3, P, C1, C2) ; tree(B3, P, C2, C1) ).
```

Then, if you formed a *transitive closure* of the extended `father4/4` predicate w.r.t. its fourth argument, it'd be as simple as

```erlang
is_under1(3, a4):- 
    transitive_closure(father4(3, a4, _), List_Of_IDs),      % pseudocode
    memberchk(a4, List_Of_IDs).
```

and then if it's `true`, you know you're in the correct subtree. You can code the conjunction by hand, it's a good exercise to get yourself a real feel for the language as well as the theoretical foundations. Consider how an apprentice must do every menial task by hand first, when they start, and only then proceed to learning the complex tools that do the job quicker. Of course a day will come when everything will be done by 3D printers, but until then (or *even* then), we can indulge in treating our trade as an art.

But coding it by hand *also* gives you a chance to make it more efficient, stopping the search as soon as the parent ID is found (in case that it *is* found):

```erlang
is_under2(3, a4):-
    father4( 3, a4, P, B3),
    ( B3 == a4 , !                   % a cut, if you would like it
    ; is_under( ... , ... ) ).       % recursive call
```

Calling it by different name helps.

Notice the recursion: `3` is under `a4` if `a4` is `3`'s father (called `B3` there), *or* if the `3`'s father is under `a4`. Makes total sense, right?

Comment: The op is using `a4` (the 2nd argument to `father`) to select the top most tree/subtree under consideration for the query. So the answer shouldn't involve any part of the tree above/beyond that point.

Comment: @lurker I address this in the answer. they asked for a hint anyway, so it's a start.